# JS callback chain confusion

Tags: javascript, extjs, callback, cordova

I have the following code mix of ST/ExtJS with Phonegap API, but this is a more general Javascript question:

When the save button on my form is tapped I call this method:

```
onSavePush: function(button) {
    var form = button.up('panel'),
    //get the record 
        record = form.getRecord(),
    //get the form values
        values = form.getValues();
    //if a new push
    if(!record){
        var newRecord = new EvaluateIt.model.SiteEvaluation(values);
        Ext.getStore('SiteEvaluations').add(newRecord);
    }
    //existing push
    else {
        record.set(values);
    }
        form.hide();
    // assemble record 
    //assemble_evaluation(record);

    initialize_image_post(record, values);

    // add file_name update to store here:

},
```

The function initialize_image_post() does what it says (sets up API url and grabs uri reference):

```
function initialize_image_post(record) {

    var uri,
        url;

    // use new API with authorization token
    url =  EvaluateIt.config.protocol;
    url += EvaluateIt.config.test;
    url += EvaluateIt.config.domain;
    // url += EvaluateIt.config.dev; // ev environment
    // url += EvaluateIt.config.file_response;  // needed for POST echo
    url += EvaluateIt.config.apiViewNomination;
    url += EvaluateIt.config.file_upload;
    url += '?token=' + sessionStorage.sessionToken;

    uri = record.data.imageUri; // local path to image

    console.log('uri: ' + uri + 'url: ' + url); 

    post_image(uri, url);
}
```

It then calls the Phonegap file transfer API in the function post_image()

```
// Phonegap file transfer
function post_image(imageUri, url) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions(),
        ft = new FileTransfer();

    options.fileKey = 'userfile';
    //options.fileName = imageUri.substr(imageUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    ft.upload(imageUri, encodeURI(url), post_success, post_error, options);
}
```

On success, I then grab the response from the server and nab the file_name so I can write it to my local data store way back in my initial method

```
function post_success(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    alert(r.response);

    var response = Ext.JSON.decode(r.response),
        file_name = response.imageData.file_name;

    alert(file_name);

    // somehow get file_name back up to onSavePush method

}
```

The problem is, to do this, I need  to get the response variable back to my onSavePush method. How do I do this? I assume I need to somehow set up a callback chain or some such thing? Grazie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to get the response in your `onSavePush` method on purpose, right? Then, with your procedural-style programming, the solution is to define the `post_success` callback within `onSavePush` and pass it down:

```
onSavePush: function(button) {
    // bablabla
    var post_success = function(r) {
        // bablabla or "add file_name update to store here"
    }
    initialize_image_post(record, values, post_success);
}

function initialize_image_post(record, values, callback) {
    // bablabla
    post_image(uri, url, callback);
}

function post_image(imageUri, url, post_success) {
    // bablabla
    ft.upload(imageUri, encodeURI(url), post_success, post_error, options);
}
```

In ideal world you could design an class/singleton that will care about posting images, fire events on success and so you could just attach one-off event handler to it in your `onSavePush`.

Comment: Danke Schoen! That works for me (I knew the solution was obvious! Doh!). And yes, there is a reason I need the response in my onSavePush method. While I don't like the procedural solution, it seemed to be the quick and dirty method for getting a prototype of my app out the door. I will try a singleton though down the road.